# Pyright not detect current pyenv environment

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, pyright

If I run the `pre-commit`

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: check-added-large-files
  - repo: https://github.com/pycqa/isort
    rev: 5.11.5
    hooks:
      - id: isort
        name: isort (python)
  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black-pre-commit-mirror
    rev: 23.12.1
    hooks:
      - id: black
        language_version: python3.11

  - repo: https://github.com/RobertCraigie/pyright-python
    rev: v1.1.343
    hooks:
    - id: pyright
```

based on `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.isort]
profile = "black"

[tool.black]
line-length=120

[tool.pyright]
#venvPath = "envs_path"
#venv="env_name"

include = ["stories"]
exclude = [
    "**/__pycache__",
    "scripts",
    "ml"
]
```

with `pre-commit run --all-files`  I keep getting like 200+ import errors, eg. :

```
 error: Import "sqlmodel" could not be resolved (reportMissingImports)
```

The only workaround is to uncomment the path and env name lines in the above toml snippet to run it, but then this can't be pushed to repo as everyoser can have arbitraty path.

How can I make the pyright to dynamically detect current `pyenv` environment while running `pre-commit` based on `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: show your configuration?

Comment: @anthonysottile I've edited and put the complete config. Thanks.